# WPF - Refresh ListView bound to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, listviewitem

I'm writing an application at the minute and have come across an issue with a ListView which displays items from a View Model; there's a property in said view model "Selected" which is just a bool and, I bind this to the ListView's "IsSelected" property.

I have a button to "Clear Selection" which iterates over each item that is selected and sets it to false; this works and the command is updated and the buttons are no longer enabled since there's nothing where `Selected == true`.

*In Pictures*

Item is selected; buttons are available.

[image: Item is selected; buttons are available.]

Button "Clear Selection" is pressed
[image: Clear Selection is pressed]

At this point, I can no longer click the control to select the element; I have to control click it to unselect it which puts everything back as disabled and nothing selected.

Here's the XAML for the control - not sure what I could be doing wrong but I'm unable to find an answer thus far.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AssignableItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource lviStyleBase}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Created" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContactCreated}" Width="Auto" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContactName}" Width="Auto" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}" Width="Auto" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```cs
namespace CSI.ViewModels
{
    public class AssignViewModel
        : ModelBase
    {
        #region Properties
        private bool viewingFilters;

        public bool Filtering
        {
            get { return viewingFilters; }
            set { if ( SetValue(ref viewingFilters, value) ) Notify(); }
        }

        private bool assigning;

        public bool Assigning
        {
            get { return assigning; }
            set { if ( SetValue(ref assigning, value) ) Notify(); }
        }

        private string viewTitle = "Assign";
        public string ViewTitle
        {
            get => $"{viewTitle}{(Filtered ? " (filtered)" : "")}";
        }

        private AssignFilterValuesModel filters;

        public AssignFilterValuesModel Filters
        {
            get { return filters; }
            set { SetValue(ref filters, value); }
        }

        public bool Filtered
        {
            get
            {
                if ( filters == null ) return false;

                return assignables.Count() != AssignableItems.Count();
            }
        }

        private bool loading;

        public bool Loading
        {
            get { return loading; }
            set { SetValue(ref loading, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<AssignableWorkItemModel> assignables;
        public ObservableCollection<AssignableWorkItemModel> AssignableItems
        {
            get
            {
                if ( assignables == null ) return null;
                if ( Filters == null ) return assignables;

                var retval = assignables.Where(x => 1 == 1);

                if ( Filters.Dealers.Any(x => x.Selected) )
                    retval = retval.Where(x => filters.Dealers.Where(o => o.Selected).Select(o => o.Key).ToList().Contains(x.Dealer));

                if ( Filters.VehicleModels.Any(x => x.Selected) )
                    retval = retval.Where(x => filters.VehicleModels.Where(o => o.Selected).Select(o => o.Key).ToList().Contains(x.VehicleModel));

                return new ObservableCollection<AssignableWorkItemModel>(retval);
            }
            set => SetValue(ref assignables, value);
        }
        private ObservableCollection<AssignableWorkItemModel> selected;
        public ObservableCollection<AssignableWorkItemModel> SelectedItems
        {
            get => selected;
            set => SetValue(ref selected, value);
        }
        #endregion
        #region Commands
        private RelayCommand displayFilterScreen;
        public void Execute_DisplayFilters(object _)
        {
            Filtering = true;
        }
        public bool CanExecute_DisplayFilters(object _) => !Filtering;
        public RelayCommand DisplayFilters
        {
            get => displayFilterScreen ?? (displayFilterScreen = new RelayCommand(Execute_DisplayFilters, CanExecute_DisplayFilters));
        }

        private RelayCommand applyFilters;
        public void Execute_ApplyFilters(object _)
        {
            Filtering = !Filtering;
            Notify(nameof(AssignableItems));
            Notify(nameof(Filtered));
            Notify(nameof(ViewTitle));
        }
        public bool CanExecute_ApplyFilters(object _) => Filtering;
        public RelayCommand ApplyFilters
        {
            get => applyFilters ?? (applyFilters = new RelayCommand(Execute_ApplyFilters, CanExecute_ApplyFilters));
        }

        private RelayCommand doAssign;
        public void Execute_Assign(object _)
        {
            UserSelectWindow us = new UserSelectWindow();
            us.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            ViewModelServer.UserSelectVM.Prompt = "Select the user you wish to assign these items to";
        }
        public bool CanExecute_Assign(object _) => !Filtering && (bool)AssignableItems?.Any(x => x.Selected);
        public RelayCommand Assign
        {
            get => doAssign ?? (doAssign = new RelayCommand(Execute_Assign, CanExecute_Assign));
        }

        private RelayCommand clrSelection;
        public void Execute_ClearSelection(object _)
        {
            AssignableItems?.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Selected = false);
        }
        public bool CanExecute_ClearSelection(object _) => (bool)AssignableItems?.Any(x => x.Selected);
        public RelayCommand ClearSelection
        {
            get => clrSelection ?? (clrSelection = new RelayCommand(Execute_ClearSelection, CanExecute_ClearSelection));
        }
        #endregion
        #region Constructors
        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code for your view models, because from the XAML alone there is no way to determine what the actual issue is. Apart from that, you can remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from `ItemsSource` and `IsSelected` as that does not have any effect. You can also remove `Mode=TwoWay` from `IsSelected`, because it binds two-way by default.

Comment: @thatguy thanks! I've added the view model to the post. Thanks for the feedback on the XAML; I thought the values were defaults anyway but, getting desperate,  thought I'd be explicit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a binding for SelectedIndex and set the value to -1 when calling ClearSelection; tip from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165143/clearselection-in-listbox-mvvm)